# MS Access place file name on a form as a label

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database where the title is `DB Ver 5.3.accdb` and when you open the tool, it auto-opens a form called the `Main Menu`. I have a Label on the form that I change every time I update the tool to match the new version of the file name. I am wondering if it is possible to pull the file name (`DB Ver 5.3.accdb`) preferably without `.accdb` such as `DB Ver 5.3` and place in on the `Main Menu` as a label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would support the answer of YowE3K about `On Load` event, but for extracting file name it would be better to use more reliable method:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Label0.Caption = .GetBaseName(CurrentDb.Name)
    End With
End Sub
```

Also I would recommend to do not change the file name for each version of application. Keep the current version of application in the table. Also add a date of build as another parameter. You can use this data for information about application more effectively, than just file name.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use an `On Load` event such as

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim thisFile As String
    thisFile = CurrentDb.Name
    thisFile = Mid(thisFile, InStrRev(thisFile, "\") + 1)
    thisFile = Left(thisFile, Len(thisFile) - 6)
    Label0.Caption = thisFile
End Sub
```